# When the Scala code in currying functions is evaluated and why?

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala code:

```scala
        maybeEvent.fold(
          logAndExecute(s"$key is not a triggered key")(().asRight[Exception])
        )(
          logAndExecute(s"$key is a triggered key")(storeAndPublishEvent(_))
        )
```

The `maybeEvent` is type of `Option[Event]` and the `logAndExecute` looks like:

```scala
  def logAndExecute[T](message: String)(executor: => T): T = {
    logger.info(message)
    executor
  }
```

When the `maybeEvent` is `None`, I got both logs:

```
key is not a triggered key
key is a triggered key
```

When I changed to code to

```scala
        maybeEvent.fold(
          logAndExecute(s"$key is not a triggered key")(().asRight[Exception])
        )(event =>
          logAndExecute(s"$key is a triggered key")(storeAndPublishEvent(event))
        )
```

The issue is fixed. Could you please enlighten me what's different and why here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My advice, try to never use the `_` syntax, it has all kinds of issues. In this case, it expands to something like: `logAndExecute(s"$key is a triggered key")(x => storeAndPublishEvent(x))` and since `logAndExecute` returns the same thing that is passed to it, then it return the function that `fold` needs, but running the logging before calling `fold`

Comment: There is a thing called expansion. But to get a clarified response it would be better to see the signature of `storeAndPublishEvent`

Answer (score 1):

- nothing about precedence, nothing about evaluation
- everything is about expansion
- `_` belongs to the inner scope
- nothing wrong with `_`, but in nested structures I would rather write `x => f(g(x))`
- `storeAndPublishEvent`  expands to `storeAndPublishEvent _`
- `storeAndPublishEvent _`  expands to `e => storeAndPublishEvent(e)`
- `storeAndPublishEvent(_)` expands to `e => storeAndPublishEvent(e)`
- you can write `val t: Event => Unit = storeAndPublishEvent` and make sure
- in scala, `Event => Unit` can be treated as another type `T`
- signature of `logAndExecute[T](message: String)(executor: => T): T` is very interesting. By writing `logAndExecute("...")(storeAndPublishEvent(_))`, `storeAndPublishEvent(_)` becomes a function (`T` = `Event => Unit`), and `logAndExecute` returns it back. And, actually very unlikely, but in your case IT CONFORMS the second parameter of `Option.fold` which is `Event => Unit`. But to produce this function, `logAndExecute` needs to be called.